# Column name from vector gets lost

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a data frame with this format:

```
DF1 <- DF0[i,6:12]  (DF0 is the original data frame I read from)
```

The resulting DF1 has the following column names:

```
DF1:  
home - train -bus -car  .. - male - female
1       3      0              0       1
```

What I do is recovering the names of the columns that are 0, e.g:

```
colNull <- colnames(DF1[,DF1==0])
```

My understanding was that this generated a series of 'values' (because in most DF0 rows, several columns are 0):

```
colNull   like  'bus','male'.....   (char type)
```

However, when only *one column* in DF1 is 0, the column names are no longer recovered and as a result colNull is NULL (class(colNull is NULL too), which I can't use.

Is there an easy fix for this? I'd also like to understand why this happens, or what I'm doing wrong. I get it's something about objects formats but not the reason behind.

Thanks in advance,      p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we subset a dataset having either a single row or if the output is a single column drop to vector while subsetting.  The default option based on `?"["` is

```
  x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
```

So either `names`

```
 names(DF1[,DF1==0])
 #[1] "bus"  "male"
```

Or using `drop=FALSE` should work

```
 colnames(DF1[,DF1==0, drop=FALSE])
 #[1] "bus"  "male"
```

Or another option is convert the logical matrix to a logical vector with `as.vector` and it should work as expected.

```
 colnames(DF1[as.vector(DF1==0)])
 #[1] "bus"  "male"
```

NOTE: This is not a general case as with more than one rows, we may need to use `colSums(DF1)==0`

#### data

```
 DF1 <- data.frame(home=1, train=3, bus=0, male=0, female=1)
```

Comment: I wonder if you could close this as a dupe with some of your own answers http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3732271+is%3Aanswer+drop+%3D+F

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for the link.  I also thought about it as a duplicate, but this may not be an exact duplicate.